# jQuery Fade-In OnLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

Okay what I am simply looking for is a short/easy script that will allow me to replace the DIV name so that I can have multiple divs on a page fadein once loaded (including images within them).

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by DIV name? ID? Class name? Title?

Comment: @Rob W: That question is irrelevant to the relevant question at hand.

Comment: @Sime Vidas: I mean ID and or Class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give the divs a common class (e.g. "fade") and use code similar to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fade").hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(3000)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5td73/

Comment: Suprisingly it's not working in my code. I have called out jQuery 1.6.4. from CDN, and have added the script in-between the head tags. Do I need to define OnLoad or call that out as well? Because the only code I have is the code that's provided within the jsFiddle. Thanks!

Comment: @AaronBrewer Yes, you are correct! You need to run the code after the page is loaded.  You can do this by either placing your script tag at the end of the body element (as I did in my fiddle) or wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()` function.  I'll update my answer with the second option.

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your javascript file, for each element you want to fade it add the `class="fadeOnLoad"` code and make sure to add `display: none` to the css for any elements you want to have hidden on load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.fadeOnLoad').fadeIn('slow');
);
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you as well sir.