# How to prevent admin layout page load before the script?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to load the script before the layout page load, please check my scenario in my attached video,

https://share.getcloudapp.com/p9uAR4JX

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    jQuery('div.custom-metabox').hide();

    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('div.custom-metabox').fadeIn('slow');
    },1000);
    
    });
```

but the layout is loading before the page. how should I prevent this, I have enqueued the script like this,

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', include_plugin_url( 'assets/js/custom.js' ), array(), $version, false );
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible to initially hide `div.custom-metabox` with CSS? That might help avoid the content showing before the window's load event fires.

Comment: yes, possible...

Comment: Another idea is to hide content as soon as the document is ready, rather than waiting for the window to load. See [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready).

Comment: As examples, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8076375/924299) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7861201/924299).

Comment: okay i am checking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide `div.custom-metabox` by css:

```css
div.custom-metabox{display:none;}
```

Register the script in footer and tells the dependancy:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', include_plugin_url( 'assets/js/custom.js' ), array('jquery'), $version, true);
```

Then you can just fade in this section after 1Sec:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('div.custom-metabox').fadeIn('slow');
    },1000);
    
});
```

Comment: My Pleasure! @NayeemHyderRiddhi